How can I use the coef argument in stargazer in R?
I am really confused how to use the coef argument in stargazer in R. I want to create a table with only a few of the coefficients in my regression. According to the function documentation, it should be "a list of numeric vectors that will replace the default coefficient values for each model. Element names will be used to match coefficients to individual covariates, and should therefore match covariate names". This is super unclear, since it first mentions numeric vectors, but then it mentions variables names (which are not numeric). I haven't found any examples that work in the internet (or ChatGPT). I don't understand the syntax needed to specify the coefficients/build this list. Can anyone provide an example, please?

a named vector in a list (since you can have multiple models in a table, one named vector for each model), list(c(x1 = 1, x2 = 2), ...)

@rawr, thanks! I was trying a table with only one model for debugging and I tried something like what you wrote, but it did not work. Let x1 be the name of my variable. Hence, I tried without sucess all of the following:
coef = list(c("x1")), coef = list(c(x1)), coef = list(c(x1 = 1)), coef = list(c("x1" = 1)), coef = list("x1") and coef = list(1)

if you are just trying to change the variable name, there are probably better ways of doing it cause you'd have to give the coefficients again redundantly

The coef command in stargazer specifies a predefined value for the coefficient. You can name a list (i.e., list("a" = 1:3, "b" = 4:6)). Here is an example (using absurd coef values for clarity)
# model
mod <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + hp + am, data = mtcars)

# table
stargazer::stargazer(mod, 
                     coef = list(c("cyl" = 400, "hp" = 200, "am" = 600)))


What the help means by

"Element names will be used to match coefficients to individual covariates, and should therefore match covariate names"

Is saying that the names of those elements have to be the same as those in your coefficients.
What I believe you want is a table with only specified coefficients (ie, not all three in the above model). To do that, use keep:
stargazer::stargazer(mod, keep = c("cyl", "hp"))


